# How do I implement Deref + DerefMut properly?

Tags: rust

Hi I have the following [this tutorial](https://os.phil-opp.com/vga-text-mode/) for learning more in depth what can I do with rust so I'm aware that this might now be the proper way to do thing. Here is the repository which contains all the [code](https://github.com/nicolae536/rust_os) to take a in depth look. I'm having a global vga writer instance which needs to be safe for data races so using `lazy_static` I initialize it. What I want to do is is to be able to aquire the lock only when I actually print the string so that I implement `fmt::Write` on the `WrappedWriter` instead of the `Writer` to not obtain the lock over the `spin::Mutex` when I want to print a string rather I want to obtain the lock after the params were formatted . But when I call this the write function:

```
crate::vga_buffer::WRITER.write_fmt(args).unwrap();
```

I get the following error:

```
   Compiling rust_os v0.1.0 (D:\Workspace\Organiztions\home\rust\rust_os)
error[E0055]: reached the recursion limit while auto-dereferencing `vga_buffer::writer::WrappedWriter`
  --> src\lib.rs:19:31
   |
19 |     crate::vga_buffer::WRITER.write_fmt(args).unwrap();
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^ deref recursion limit reached
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="256"]` attribute to your crate (`rust_os`)

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0055`.
error: could not compile `rust_os`.
```

Here is the implementation of the `Writer` + `WrappedWriter`

```
use core::fmt;

use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use volatile::Volatile;

use super::color::*;
use super::screen_character;
use core::ops::{DerefMut, Deref};

// #[allow(dead_code)]
// use crate::serial_print;
// use crate::serial_println;

pub const BUFFER_HEIGHT: usize = 25;
pub const BUFFER_WIDTH: usize = 80;

#[repr(transparent)]
struct Buffer {
    chars: [[Volatile<screen_character::ScreenCharacter>; BUFFER_WIDTH]; BUFFER_HEIGHT],
}

pub struct Writer {
    column_position: usize,
    color_code: ColorCode,
    buffer: &'static mut Buffer,
}

impl Writer {
    pub fn new(column_position: usize,
               color_code: ColorCode) -> Writer {
        return Writer {
            column_position,
            color_code,
            buffer: unsafe { &mut *(0xb8000 as *mut Buffer) },
        };
    }
}

impl Writer {
    pub fn write_byte(&mut self, byte: u8) {
        match byte {
            b'\n' => self.new_line(),
            byte => {
                if self.column_position >= BUFFER_WIDTH {
                    self.new_line();
                }

                let row = BUFFER_HEIGHT - 1;
                let col = self.column_position;

                let color_code = self.color_code;
                self.buffer.chars[row][col].write(screen_character::ScreenCharacter::new(byte, color_code));
                self.column_position += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn write_string(&mut self, s: &str) {
        for byte in s.bytes() {
            match byte {
                // printable ASCII byte or newline
                0x20..=0x7e | b'\n' => self.write_byte(byte),
                // not part of printable ASCII range
                _ => self.write_byte(0xfe),
            }
        }
    }

    fn new_line(&mut self) {
        for row in 1..BUFFER_HEIGHT {
            for col in 0..BUFFER_WIDTH {
                let current_character = self.buffer.chars[row][col].read();
                self.buffer.chars[row - 1][col].write(current_character);
            }
        }
        self.clear_row(BUFFER_HEIGHT - 1);
        self.column_position = 0;
    }

    fn clear_row(&mut self, row_index: usize) {
        let blank = screen_character::ScreenCharacter::new(b' ', self.color_code);
        for col in 0..BUFFER_WIDTH {
            self.buffer.chars[row_index][col].write(blank);
        }
    }
}

// impl fmt::Write for Writer {
//     fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> fmt::Result {
//         self.write_string(s);
//         Ok(())
//     }
// }

struct WrappedWriter {
    value: spin::Mutex<Writer>
}

impl fmt::Write for WrappedWriter {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> fmt::Result {
        self.value.lock().write_string(s);
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl Deref for WrappedWriter {
    type Target = WrappedWriter;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        return self;
    }
}

impl DerefMut for WrappedWriter {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        return self;
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref WRITER: WrappedWriter = {
        let writerInstance = WrappedWriter {
            value: spin::Mutex::new(
                Writer::new(0, ColorCode::new(Color::Yellow, Color::Black))
            )
        };
        writerInstance
    };
}

#[test_case]
fn test_println_output() {
    let test_str = "Some test string that fits on a single line";
    println!("{}", test_str);
    for (char_index, char) in test_str.chars().enumerate() {
        let screen_char = WRITER.value.lock().buffer.chars[BUFFER_HEIGHT - 2][char_index].read();
        assert_eq!(char::from(screen_char.ascii_character), char);
    }
}
```

`Deref` + `DerefMut` Were implemented because I get the following error without them but then again I didn't knew on what should I deref cause I don't actually need to deref from my point of view this are needed because `write_fmt` gets a mut of self

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a dereference of `vga_buffer::writer::WRITER` as mutable
  --> src\lib.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     crate::vga_buffer::WRITER.write_fmt(args).unwrap();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `vga_buffer::writer::WRITER`
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the point of implementing Deref/DerefMut like that. They're normally used for exposing some inner value, but it seems like there's no need to expose the `Writer` (ingoring the mutex hurdle). Is there a reason you added it?

Comment: Also is your tutorial link right? I don't see how double-fault handling is relevant to the code in question.

Comment: Yes it's right when a double fault occures the program panics and the panic handler uses the writer which if it has arguments for printing emits another error because the writer it's already locked here the problem is described https://github.com/phil-opp/blog_os/issues/831. What I did first is implementing it without a deref + deref_mut but than I got an error related to deref on calling the function mentioned above

Comment: @kmdreko I added also the original error

Comment: I see, it might've been better to link the tutorial on [VGA text mode](https://os.phil-opp.com/vga-text-mode/) since that is where the OP implements `WRITER`, differently than you have here. Your core issue is from trying to call a `mut` function from a non-`mut` static, which you [can do by making it mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/static-items.html#mutable-statics) though I'm not familiar enough with lazy_static to answer that properly, if that is the route you want to go

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks kindof that's the path I want to go but I found that the problem is not originating from there. But this is still a valid problem in the implementation I will have a read over the `lazy_static` to see if I can declare that global ref as mut cause basically this is what I need. Or from what I discussed with a friend with more experience in rust maybe it's a better way of doing this with the writter itself making him support mutiple threads safely

Answer (score 1):

`WrappedWriter` currently derefs to itself, which derefs to itself, which derefs to itself, and so on, which is why you reach the recursion limit. You probably want to make it deref to the `Writer` inside by obtaining a lock.

Comment: I agree. I added some more details why I implemented them like this cause I don't actually want to aquire the lock the this deref happens if I'm write he tries to deref  when he calls `write_fmt` but then I actually want is to format the arguments and then call the lock() + wirte to the buffer